# Pivot table help - Select all accounts started with a certain number

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with 1000s of accounts in the following format 4xxxxx, starting with 4,5,6,and 7. I'm trying to select all accounts started with 7 without selecting them one by one. Is there a shortcut I could use? Thanks!

Comment: In the filter section of the PivotField enter 7*

Answer (score 0):

In the Pivot Table fields select the item and use the label filters. There is an option for begins with

[image]